# How do I use the Logitech Webcam 9000 on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, webcam, mouse

I have OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion installed on my Macbook Pro. I want to use my Logitech Quickcam Pro 9000 webcam with it, but [Logitech does not include drivers for OS X](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/webcams/3056).

I need an camera that is not on the laptop.

Is there third-party software I can use to make this work on my MacBook?

Comment: The Logitech site you link to seems to imply that you *don't need* a driver. Have you tried the camera in your Mac? It seems like it should "just work". What actual problem are you encountering? Does the camera work on a Windows computer?

Comment: @CajunLuke - I plugged the camera in, but Skype did not pick it up.  Maybe I need a reboot for that to work.  Yes, that camera has worked on several Windows environments for a few years now.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Logitech Pro 9000 webcam (which shows up as a Miscellaneous Device in System Profiler, see below) under Mac OS X 10.8.2.

[image]

No drivers are required. Simply plug the camera in, then launch a video-enabled application (such as Skype.) You should be able to select the camera as a video device within the app without further ado:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a Logitech Webcam 9000. It's a very good 720p camera with an excellent microphone. Unfortunately, this camera is no longer working out of the box under El Capitan 10.11.5.

The video instructions above don't work for current Skype 7.44 or for Photo Booth 8.0.

It's possible to get the microphone working under 10.11.5 by following these steps:

1. Open Audio Midi Setup from `/Applications/Utilities/`
2. Select the `Unknown USB Audio Device` by clicking on it in the left pane. This is the Logitech Webcam 9000, as recognized by OSX.
3. Click on `Input` on the Right Pane
4. In the format dropdown, select a different Hz from what is already selected.
5. Now in the Volume Tab right under the format dropdown, fiddle with the volume bar, decreasing it all the way and then increasing it to the max.

[image: Logitech Webcam 9000 masquerading as Unknown Audio Device in Audio MIDI Setup]

And now your microphone should work again. [Untreated sample recording attached](http://screenshots.foliovision.com/2c2Y1F0z2T2G/20180122-fragment-of-sir-john-suckling-loving-and-beloved.m4a) from SoundStudio as quality demo (fragment from Loving and Beloved, Sir John Suckling).

Since the camera part no longer works, I've mounted my Logitech Webcam 9000 on a mic stand to use for podcasts as a guest. If I decide to host, I'll have to make one of my fancier mikes work with OS X but this mic is a great start. Webcam makers do not often include microphones this good any more (the Webcam 9000 was pretty expensive in its day).

Answer (score 0):

I am running Catalina 10.15.6 on my MacBook pro, and the 9000 works right out of the box - no driver needed.  Granted, it did some pretty fancy stuff when it lived on my PC with the Logitech software, but for basic video conferencing (Skype,Zoom,Meets) it works just fine - audio and video.